# Entity Framework Core - Creating a dynamic DbSet Model from TableName

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let's say we have a few clients, and each client has a Database with a "Employees" table, but for each client the table is a little different. Most of the columns are the same, but there are a few clients with more/less columns for that table.

I currently have an "Employee" class that represents the basic table, which is used in my DbContext in the DbSet.
Eventually I would like to just make some CRUD operations on that table.

Using EFCore, I'm having some trouble writing a generic code, that will work for all clients, regardless of how many columns they have for that table.
(The tableName stays the same for all clients)

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Maybe creating the Entity dynamically? Or extending the current "Employee" class?

Comment: Why do you have different columns for the same entity for your "Employees" table? What are the additional columns for the different clients and are they required for the "Employees" table?

Comment: Employee in this example represents a different class for my organization, its just an example. Each client has different columns for the table that represents the "Employee", because these are the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 common ways to implement **inheritance**

- Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)
- Table Per Type (TPT)
- Table Per Concrete Type (TPC)

In EF core only the first one is applicable. Additionally, you can specify a name and data type for the discriminator column and the values to represent each type. In case you use fluent config it would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .ToTable("Employee")
    .HasDiscriminator<int>("EmployeeType")
    .HasValue<Vanilla>(1)
    .HasValue<Customer1>(2)
    .HasValue<Customer2>(3);
```

This would store all values in one table and Costumer1 specific values would be nulls if it is not Customer1. I made the vanilla as you said "more/less columns" and Employee would be true base class common for all.

Additionally, here is an example how to set up [table per hierarchy](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/inheritance/table-per-hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have no knowledge about how many and which columns are added for each customer? Maybe I need something like a "Place Holder" , some kind of object that can accept any number of columns without knowing which type each one will be? (simple types only)

Comment: Personally I use an ssis package in that case that imports the data from external system to local db adding synctime locks and few extra fields to keep track when the data was imprted. This is put on a different db and imported from there later. Additionally I also have a 2 part sync chron job that that does this and it runs every 10 min. Furthermore I have a chron job that does the export as well, but it runs once a day and serializes the changes in xml. The external system can parse and make changes accordingly.